# What textbook is being used in these lectures (Linear Algebra)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning Linear Algebra from these lectures by Prof. Adrian Banner (Princeton University) Does anyone know what textbook they are using?

This is a link to the playlist on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGqzsq0erqU7w7ZrTZ-pWWk4-AOkiGEGp

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they use the same textbook at the course (MAT202 at Princeton), it appears to be Linear Algebra with Applications by Otto Bretscher. See http://www.math.princeton.edu/undergraduate/course/mat202.

Comment: thanks man for this, looks like it's a horrible book according to Amazon.com :)